# Fire does not show in final render

Tags: rendering, transparency, smoke-simulation

I made a campfire, but when I render it the fire does not show in the rendered image. I've put all the textures and the .blend in a Google Drive [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B1zwMJkEIn5AWlhrc0FOVDhhM2c).

Thank you,
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Were you hoping for something more like the following (frame 8)?

[image]

If you were, you needed to change the material, *Material*, from a *Transparent BSDF* to the following node setup. This is pulled from the [Vfx Blender](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMUKl8sPATN4T7c8ktGmwDw)'s YouTube video, [How to kick a Fireball (blender tutorial) [HD] part 1](https://youtu.be/VueSBzrIh1o).

As I understand it, it uses the *Attribute* nodes to determine what part of the cube's volume is smoke and what is fire. The *ColorRamp* obviously colors the fire, and the *Math > Multiply* node set to *9.000* determines how transparent the fire is (*0* being clear). The *Math > Multiply* node set to *7.500* determines how transparent the smoke is (*0* being clear).

[image]

Here is the adjusted .blend file (w/o textures because they didn't come through Google Drive):

[image]

Comment: @AJ.vdw200 If my answer helped, please consider marking it as accepted by selecting the check mark in its upper, left-hand corner. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!